# Why can't mother see son's Upanayana ceremony?

Tags: upanayanam

Recently in March 2020 month, we performed the [Munj/Thread/Janeau/Upanayana ceremony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upanayana) of my 10 year old son. During the actual Muhurtam time ritual (which was at 9:52 am), my wife was not allowed to view this ceremony according to the Hindu ritual.

Is this a traditional practice in Munj ceremony? Why can't a mother see this specific ritual? What are the reasons for the same?

My personal opinion :

Mother should be allowed to view this ritual in "Munj" ceremony.

Comment: the maha mantra is not supposed to be taught to or chanted by any non-dwija (those who are not qualified to wear sacred-thread). that is why they cover the mantra-upadesa with a cloth, and ideally only father and son should be there (4 ears), but nowadays even father doesn't know mantra, so the guru is also inside the cloth (6 ears). so your personal opinion is not accepted by shastras.

Comment: Thanks Ram. But other people are able to view this ritual other than mother for the mantra said by father to son in the cloth.

Comment: wait.. what did you mean by mother is not allowed to see the ritual - did you mean not allowed to see inside the cloth, or not allowed in the mandap itself ? maunji dharan is wearing a thread around the waist - so it's possible they did it because the boy has grown up and should not be seen naked by mother anymore

Comment: Thanks Ram. The Mother is able to watch all the rituals except the Muhurtam time where the father offers a garland to his son and son offering a garland to his father similar to a marriage. This ritual is excluded to be watched by mother which occurs at Muhurtam time. What are the reasons?

Comment: right tying the maunji rope is the first time the boy is considered 'grown up' - till then he runs around naked in front of the mother. that's my guess, so it's better to ask your purohit itself directly

Comment: Thanks Ram. Only the ritual during Muhurtam time where the garland exchange takes between father & son similar to marriage is excluded to be watched by the boy's mother. All other rituals are watched by the boy's mother in Upanayana ceremony. Why only this ritual? It happened in my Son's Upanayana ceremony.